# Are Shisha Pens Halaal?

Tags: halal-haram, health

The recent introduction of Shisha Pens (Also called E-Cigarettes) have become widespread throughout Islamic communities. Many people say it is just water vapour and that they are not harmful. However, through my research, I have found some people who have suggested otherwise.

Are they Halaal or Haram? And why?

Comment: Are they harmful to your body?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, although, the general consensus I am receiving is that they are not.

Comment: This is more of a medical question than Islamic. Islam's stand is clear: if something is harmful to one's health, than it is not halal to consume it without valid reasons and purpose.

Comment: you would like to describe a little bit about, "**What is Shisha Pens?**"

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16815/is-smoking-allowed-in-islam this answer can help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is smoking shisha/pipe haram?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11779/is-smoking-shisha-pipe-haram)

Comment: @Sayyid, No, that question is referring to something else, when I have time, Ill edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like by a [few sources](http://islamqa.info/en/201512),  the conclusion is that if they are harmful,  then they are haram.

> But if there are types that are proven, by means of examinations and laboratory tests carried out by trustworthy scientists, to contain natural flavourings only, and they do not contain any haraam substances and are not harmful to the users or others, then in that case it is not haraam to use these safe kinds. The ruling depends on whether the reason for it is present or not.

I would argue that,  contrary to the article above, from IslamQA, that even e-cigarettes with just nicotine are harmful. This is backed up (in part ) by the below paper, as well as stating even without nicotine (the active ingredient) they are still harmful:
[E-Cigarette Vapor—Even when Nicotine-Free—Found to Damage Lung Cells](http://www.the-aps.org/mm/hp/Audiences/Public-Press/2015/25.html)

Comment: I thought it was also sinful/makruh to come close to the sin. Is that also the case here?

Comment: @Dinar I am not a scholar, but it is often safest to take the most cautious approach.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your view: Some people consider smoking to be *haram*, and some consider it *makruh*.

Smoking shisha, contrary to people's belief, is harmful. But since e-cigs claim not to be harmful, this would make them neither *haram* nor *makruh*.

However, if these studies are proven to be wrong and they *are* harmful, then again you have to go back to your own view of whether you see smoking as *haram* or *makruh* in and of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Stop making Islam so complicating and hard religion. The Vaping hasn't prove to be harmful. The articles you read against them are spearheaded and paid by tobacco companies. I was smoker for 35 years and then i quit smoking with the help of Vaping. The Shisha and vaping is very different thing as well. Vaping doesn't burn anything after switching to vaping. i do not have lungs issue. I do not breathe badly or get out of air. No more asthma and issues like that. I have a lot better stamina and i can work out and run 5 miles a day while smoking i can not even walk properly. So, i do not think Vaping is Haram.

Answer (score -1):

Shisha pens and big shisha is makrooh also I saw big molanas, qaris, imams doing big shisha in a park and see from my local masjid

Comment: The question isn't just asking for the ruling; it's clearly asking *why*. And pretty much everything past the first part of the sentence is wholly irrelevant to the question asked. I would strongly recommend you read our help centre post on "[How do I write a good answer?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" to better understand the sorts of posts we encourage here; as written, this has a very high chance of being deleted.

Answer (score -1):

Even if it's 95% safe ecigs are still haram for two reasons: The intention and the cost of it. You are paying for e-liquid to supply your ecig fir no beneficial reasons and this money will add up overtime to result a huge total of money wasted. The intention would be that you are found shisha because it makes you look good or it tastes nice and this bad as just like masturbating and how it feels nice but is haram. You can only do ecigs as an alternative to cigarettes to stop the addiction (if you have no nicotine in your ecig) but many people like teenagers straight away, from not doing any bad things, go to ecigs. So therefore ecigs are haram.

Answer (score -3):

shisha pen is not haram,as it is not harmful and will not effect your health problems to take you out of the religion.